# convert sql to linq with left outer join

Tags: linq

I have a sql having left outer join, I want to convert it to linq. the sql is

```
Select P.Surname, P.Othername H.history
from customers P left outer join historyfiles H on H.patID = P.patId 
     and H.category1 = 4 
where P.id = 2299
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Comment: Except of that this one has an additional condition in the join (which only affects the right part of the join).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var query = from p in db.customers.Where(t => t.id == 2299 )
            join h in db.historyfiles.Where(l => l.category1 == 4 ) on p.patID equals h.patID into gj
            from h in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { p.Surname, p.Othername, h.History };
```

Comment: Once you decided to answer, it would be nice if you also include some explanation. And of course make sure what you post at least compiles. Your does not, because it's missing the essential part for the issue - 'into gj` is not enough, it needs to be followed by `from h in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: Thank you for response i edited my answer @IvanStoev